# How do I create a very simple hyperlink on index.html with flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

Here is my structure:

```
├── main.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   └── main.css
│   ├── img
│   │   └── main_bkg.jpg
│   └── js
└── templates
    ├── myApp
    │   └── myApp.main.html
    └── index.html
```

I just want to create a very simple hyperlink on `index.html` that links to `myApp.main.html`.

My `main.py` looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/<module>/')
def myApp(module):
    return render_template('{0}/{0}.main.html'.format(module)) 

@app.route('/user/<username>')
def show_user_profile(username):
    return 'User %s' % username

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

In my `index.html`:
I tried

```
<a href="{{ url_for('myApp') }}"><button>myApp</button></a>
```

The flask prompts BuildError `BuildError: ('myApp', {}, None)`

If I try the following on the `myApp.main.html`, then it provides a valid link back to home page:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('index') }}"><button>Home</button></a>
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: Have you tried to return a static HTML file through the `myApp` route? The error might be raised when the decorator notation is transferred into an app-route while building. Returning a static HTML file or even a string would help to identify whether the error comes from the HTML file or the route itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `myApp` rule takes a `module` parameter.  You didn't pass that to `url_for`, so it raised an error because it needs that information to build a url.

```
url_for('myApp', module='myModule')
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the structure:

`├── app.py
├── static
└── templates
    ├── Homep.html
    └── index.html`

and I used the HTML:

`<a href="{{ url_for('index') }}"><button>Home</button></a>`

It worked fine with me.